# how to use php command line after connect to remote server from ftp

Tags: php, ftp

this is very simple question for some of you but I am having a hard time doing this. So I am using a mac and I connected to the ftp server through the terminal.
$ ftp ftp.server.com
after entering username and password I am connected and I see the ftp prompt
ftp>
Now  I am trying to execute my php files here but it says invalid command, for example:

ftp> php test.php

what am I doing wrong? how do I run my php files in the remote server?
?invalid command

Comment: you need to ssh in `ssh username@server-ip-or-domain`

Comment: FTP is just for transfering files, you can't run arbitrary commands with it.

Comment: ssh\telent is the way you access the server to play on the command line

Answer (score 1):

You can't use shell commands with ftp connection. Use "help" to show ftp commands